# Using Light Socket power adapter with a motion sensor

Tags: light-fixture, motion-sensor

I have a LED shop light with a short power cord next to a light socket. I have an adapter to plug the cord into the light socket (Leviton 125V 660W Max). Wanted to add a motion sensor, so I bought one that screws into the socket, then the bulb screws into the bottom, but the bottom socket won't accept the adapter. Here's a link to the amazon page for this motion sensor: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0BQ6W4NPR/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BQ6W4NPR)
[[image: Leviton 125V 660W Power Adapter][1]]

[image: Motion Sensor]

The threads are somehow different. The Motion sensor fits the original socket. An A19 bulb fits in both the original socket and the motion sensor's socket. But that same power adapter that works in the original socket won't thread into the motion sensor's socket. It was my understanding they were the same socket type, so it feels like I'm going crazy. Am I missing something?

To clarify: The A19 Bulb AND the power adapter fit into the original light socket, but only the bulb fits into the motion sensor's socket.

Comment: Define "won't fit". Photos might help

Comment: Brands/models & links to the product pages would help a lot, too.

Comment: Can you screw a standard light bulb into the motion sensor?

Comment: Yes, a standard A19 bulb fits into the socket and the motion sensor. The power adapter fits into the socket, but not the sensor.